# Which novels does the Bungaku Shoujo movie cover?

Tags: bungaku-shoujo

I would like to watch the [Bungaku Shoujo movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_Girl_%28film%29) at some point, but I don't want spoilers for the novels. Skimming over the Wikipedia page, it seems that some events haven't happened yet as of the end of the fourth novel, while other events seem to correspond to earlier novels. There may be other spoilers, some of them major, and that also makes me afraid to research this topic too deeply on my own.

Which novels provide the major plot points for the movie? Please use spoiler tags as appropriate.

[image: Touko and a book with surprisingly few tooth marks]

Comment: +1, while kinda irrelevant to add the picture to the question it does make the question look better with it (or i suppose the question's usefulness too)

Comment: @Memor-X I couldn't resist, I love Miho Takeoka's art for Bungaku Shoujo. I was hoping a few people might see the picture and decide to check out this under-appreciated series. If you think it's too irrelevant, I'll edit to remove.

Comment: you certainly achieved that, light novel sounds interesting and since Yen Press has released them in English i might just hunt down the books myself. by irrelevant i mainly mean that normally if an image is post it's normally related to the point of the question/answer, in this case i can't really see that but as i said it makes the question look better so don't remove it!

Comment: @Memor-X They've got some pretty intense shoujo melodrama to them, which might drive off some people, but I didn't mind, and I loved the art and all the references to classical literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read the first 5 novels and from what I see, the main plot of the movie is basically the 5th novel (which is also the thickest one), though there are some parts of the other novels in there too, especially in the beginning and in the end (after the scene in the planetarium).